# Is there a way to verify more than one thing at once in one go with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, authentication

I am building a Login function that check if the username and password combination is located in database.

But while I do this, I would like to also check if the username and password combo is an active account. Therefore I would be able to tell the user if they cant log in because their account is not active or if their pass word is incorrect.

I wanted to know if there is a way that I can do both checks in one go. Currently I have setup a sequential search, that gets the pass/user combo first, then checks if their account is active. This way I doubling the amount of queries for a single login, not good.

Here is what I have so far.

```
$selectUser = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE Username=? And Pass=?";
            $loginStmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $selectUser);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($loginStmt, 'ss', $u1, $p1);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($loginStmt))
            {
                mysqli_close($link);
                die("The system is not available, try again later");
            }
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($loginStmt);
            $row_cnt = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($loginStmt);
            if ($row_cnt == 0)
            {
                $Error .= 'Invalid Username/Password. <br />';
            }
            else
            {
                $isActive = "SELECT isActivated FROM User WHERE Username=? And Pass=?";
                $isActiveStmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $isActive);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($isActiveStmt, 'ss', $u1, $p1);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($isActiveStmt,$active);
                mysqli_stmt_fetch($isActiveStmt);
                if($active != 1)
                {
                    $Error = 'Your account has not been activated yet, check email or contact admin'.
                }
                else
                {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($loginStmt, $lname, $fname);
                    mysqli_stmt_fetch($loginStmt);
                    $_SESSION['Name'] = $lname." ".$fname; 
                    $_SESSION['Username'] = $txtUsername;
                    header("Location: Default.php");
                    //mysqli_close($link);
                    //$Error = "success";
                    exit();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Erm, change the first query to `SELECT FirstName, LastName, isActivated FROM User WHERE Username=? And Pass=?` and it will return it in your array with first and last names....?

Comment: The answer to your post is "don't". Do not store plaintext passwords in the database and do *not* tell users whether the username or the password is incorrect. This gives a lot information to potential attackers.

Comment: its hashed with sha1. I wont store plain text, totally over thought that one jon.

Comment: hashed with sha1 is not good enough, it needs to be salted, which means looking up the password for the user to see what the salt is.

Comment: sha1 is horrible to use for this. consider a slow hashing algorithm like bcrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to run the second SQL
SELECT isActivated FROM User WHERE Username=? And Pass=?

If the username and pass does not exist, the $row_cnt will be 0.
if it is not 0, you can look at the isActivated column.